# Exception when starting tomcat with user account

Tags: tomcat, ssl, centos

I'm using Centos6 64bit.
I start tomcat and using SSL with root account => OK, no problem.

Now I need to start tomcat with User (not root) account.
With non SSL => OK. With SSL, some exceptions occurs after starting tomcat.

```
14-Jul-2014 10:43:28.123 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
14-Jul-2014 10:43:28.138 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:727)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:834)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
14-Jul-2014 10:43:28.140 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:834)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:414)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:406)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:727)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the steps [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Permission+Denied+Error+when+Binding+a+Port) to be perfect.

> If using Linux 2.6.24 or later, you can set up a file capability on
> the java executable, to give elevated privileges to allow opening
> privileged ports only, and no other superuser privileges:
>
> ```
> # setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep /path/to/bin/java
> ```
>
> After setting this you may notice errors when starting Java like this,
> for example:
>
> ```
> $ java -version
> /path/to/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> This means that the library is being imported from a dynamic path, and
> not in the trusted ld.so path. See
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7157699 for details. To fix
> this, you need to locate the library, and add its path to the ld.so
> configuration. Note that the below is an example, and this may differ
> depending on Linux distribution. Replace JAVA_HOME with the correct
> location:
>
> ```
> $ find JAVA_HOME -name 'libjli.so'
> JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
>
>
> # echo "JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/jli" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java-libjli.conf
> # ldconfig -v
> ```